# Visual Studio Code - Missing Icon "Run Pyrhon File in Terminal" circa 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have 2 computers running windows seven. Have installed in an interval of two weeks the same version of VsCode ( 1.37.1 ), same Python MS extension and code runner.
Same other extensions and same settings.json file.

I have noticed that In one of them I have the super useful icon “Run Python File in Terminal”. The other one I don’t have it.

I couldn’t find where to activate it. 
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Could you post the name of the Python extensions you're using in VS Code?

Comment: Sure! Both computers the same verions (one at work and one at home)

Comment: ! https://imgur.com/a/e671Yvp

Comment: ! https://imgur.com/a/ReJWsmA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [command 'python.execInTerminal-icon' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312959/command-python-execinterminal-icon-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

The icon is part of an A/B test, so installations are randomly assigned to be in/out of the experiment. We should be making it available to everyone in the near future.