# command 'python.execSelectionInTerminal' not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner just shifted from jupyter to vs-code, whenever I try to run my code, I get:

> "command 'python.execSelectionInTerminal' not found"

I have tried:

1. Uninstalling-reinstalling Python extension
2. downgrading the version
3. uninstalling and reinstalling vs code and Python
4. Restarting the system

Please Help

Comment: Have you tired resetting the keybind? (`cmd/ctrl + shift + p` -> `>keyboard`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [command 'python.execInTerminal-icon' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312959/command-python-execinterminal-icon-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you are in restricted mode. Switching from restricted mode to trusted mode worked for me. Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).